# SVG background cover not working in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I am trying to use an SVG file as my background, and it seems whatever I try, I cannot get it to cover properly in IE. it always centers the item with large amounts of space of each side. In firefox, and chrome, it works just fine. My code is as follows (I am using bootstrap FYI):

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="pull-left header-fix" runat="server" href="~/"><img src="/images/nait_logo_header.png" alt="nait logo" height="40"/><span style="margin-left:10px;"></span>Pathways<%--<i aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="font-size:medium; opacity:0.6;"></i> --%></a> 
                    <a href="~/"></a>
                </div>
     .......
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background:url(../images/header_bg.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-color: #085157;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #085157;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
  box-shadow:         0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);

  /*Tried this, doesnt work.
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/header_bg.svg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/header_bg.svg', sizingMethod='scale')";*/

}
```

I have also tried `background: url(../images/header_bg.svg) no-repeat center center fixed;`  But seems like it just blows up the svg.

Comment: Did you try converting the file? Like SVG to JPEG?

Comment: Hi, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: It's IE11. I would rather keep it a vector image if possible for it to be resizable across all monitor sizes